# How to put math equations in a "spoiler" block?

Tags: bug, mathjax, spoilers

I wanted to do something like

```
>! \begin{align}
    >! x &= 42
    >! \end{align}
```

(Unfortunately even this code block is badly formated! Why is it indented this way?)

but the result is just poor

> ! \begin{align}
> >! x &= 42
> >! \end{align}

Comment: We can only guess [what question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life,_the_Universe,_and_Everything)  you have been answering there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A work around is to put all the math on one "line".

```
>! \begin{align} x &= 42 \end{align}
```

Gives

> \begin{align} x &= 42 \end{align}

I think the reason is that to **solve other bugs**, once you enter a math environment the MarkDown stop getting processed. So the `>!` that appears before and after `x&= 42` are considered by the software as part of the math environment, and *not* part of MarkDown.

Comment: In so far as the "other bugs" are concerned: otherwise you will have to type two backslashes `\\ ` in the place where one would've done (for example, `\\{` for open brace). This was implemented to address community needs: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1409/1543  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1545/1543 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2330/1543 http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3166/1543