# Is it possible to spoiler multi-line mathjax?

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, markdown-preview, spoilers

I can't work out how to do it.

This:

```
>! $$a=b$$
>! $$b=c$$
>! $$c=d$$
```

Produces this:

> $$a=b$$
>  $$b=c$$
>  $$c=d$$

Whereas this:

```
> $$a=b$$
> $$b=c$$
> $$c=d$$
```

Produces this:

> $$a=b$$
>   $$b=c$$
>   $$c=d$$

---

**Edit:** Good joke on me.  Evidently the bug only affects the editing preview.  When the post is actually *posted*, it appears as expected.  (If you click "edit" on my question and look at the preview, you'll see the problem I thought was present.)

Still would be nice to get fixed but hardly vital.

Answer (score 8):

If you ever want to do such, I would recommend the alternative format:

```
>! \begin{align} a=b \\ b=c \\ c=d \end{align}
```

> \begin{align} a=b \\ b=c \\ c=d \end{align}

This allows multiple lines, as well as allowing preview while editing. The problem occurs any time you attempt to do dollar signs with multi-line spoilers.

One may also wish to implement another approach:

```
>! $$ a=b \\ b=c \\ c=d$$
```

> $$ a=b \\ b=c \\ c=d$$

However, [this will preview](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/26946/edit) inline equations rather than allowing the normal display format.

Answer (score 5):

This will be fixed in the next build.

When doing a preview, transformations are run on the rendered HTML, looking for a `!` at the beginning of lines in a `<blockquote>`, stripping them out, and adding the spoiler style.  This boils down to code somewhere that ran `html.replace('! $$a = b$$', '$$a = b$$')`.

Unfortunately, because JavaScript overloads `replace` with both string and regular expression replacement, the replacement string was subject to the regular expression template format, where `$` is a special character and `$$` gets transformed to `$`.  This turned your block MathJax into inline MathJax.

The fix was to escape the replacement string, converting each `$` to `$$` so it would escape, but since we're using `replace` to do that, it looks like `'$$a = b$$'.replace('$', '$$$$')`.

Answer (score 2):

Good joke on me.  Evidently the bug only affects the editing preview.  When the post is actually *posted*, it appears as expected.  (If you click "edit" on my question and look at the preview, you'll see the problem I thought was present.)

Still would be nice to get fixed but hardly vital.

Comment: Probably it would be good to include this as an addition to the question - so that others know what you are asking. (At the moment this seems basically as a duplicate of [“Big” TeX won't get hidden by `!>`?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10906) or [How to put math equations in a “spoiler” block?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9297) (And several other posts [linked to the first one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/10906) and [to the latter](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/9297).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak, good point; done.